# Session error on heroku with Node.js and Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express

I'm getting the following error when deploying my app to heroku. I don't have any errors on `localhost`. What am I missing here?

> GET / 304 522ms  GET /public/stylesheets/bootstrap.css 200 15ms -
>   131.2kb  GET /public/stylesheets/style.css 200 3ms - 799b  GET /public/images/food2.jpg 200 62ms - 812.2kb 
>   /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:242
>
> ```
>      throw message;       
>             ^    **Error: Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions**  at
> ```
>
> /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:161:23  at
>   /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1404:28
>   at
>   /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1542:30
>   at
>   /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:159:22
>   at
>   /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:685:39
>   at Cursor.close
>   (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:959:5)
>   at commandHandler
>   (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:685:21)
>   at
>   /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1806:9
>   at Server.Base._callHandler
>   (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:442:41)
>   at
>   /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:485:18

The github project is [here](https://github.com/brendancwood/nodeRestaurantApp).

```
  var express = require('express');
  var path = require('path');
  var favicon = require('static-favicon');
  var logger = require('morgan');
  var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var session = require('express-session');
  var connect = require('connect');
  var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

  var app = express();


  //mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/restaurants');
  // new database from mongohq
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://userid:password@kahana.mongohq.com:10097/app27253116');

  app.use(session({
    secret: 'asdfghjkl',
    store: new MongoStore({
      db: 'restaurants',
      collection: 'sessions',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017
    }),
    cookie: {maxAge: 900000}
  }));
```

I've also tried this code and get the same error:

```
  app.use(session({
    secret: 'asdfghjkl',
    store: new MongoStore({
      db: 'app27253116',
      collection: 'sessions',
      host: 'kahana.mongohq.com',
      port: 10097
    }),
    cookie: {maxAge: 900000}
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 store: new MongoStore({
      db: 'restaurants',
      collection: 'sessions',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      auto_reconnect:true
 }),
```